# Obter value de input

Tags: python-3.x

Olá gostaria de saber como posso obter um value de um input de uma página depois de realizar um curl com requests no python 3.6!

Exemplo:

```
<input type="hidden" name="authURL" value="1526610106833.UG2TCP2ZiJ9HKXhlrlgybcdEBB0=" data-reactid="37"/>
```

Queria pegar o conteúdo do "value", que muda a cada request, e utilizar-lo no header para outro curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quiseres fazer com regex:

```
import re

html = '<input type="hidden" name="authURL" value="1526610106833.UG2TCP2ZiJ9HKXhlrlgybcdEBB0=" data-reactid="37"/>'

match = re.compile('name="authURL" value="(.*?)"').search(html)
if match == None:
  print('Não encontrado')
else:
  print(match.group(1)) # 1526610106833.UG2TCP2ZiJ9HKXhlrlgybcdEBB0=
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/NoisyJointScope)

Com [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup) (recomendado):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '<input type="hidden" name="authURL" value="1526610106833.UG2TCP2ZiJ9HKXhlrlgybcdEBB0=" data-reactid="37"/>'

soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
inp = soup.find('input', {'name': 'authURL'})
print(inp.get('value')) # 1526610106833.UG2TCP2ZiJ9HKXhlrlgybcdEBB0=
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/AdmiredSmoothJavadocs)

Comment: Amigo, eu preciso pegar o value do authurl de um link, esse authurl muda nesse tal link a cada vez que eu dou refresh na página, como proceder ?

Comment: @Gennie tendo o html (resposta do servidor) podes ir buscar o value ao input, desta maneira e usa-lo como quiseres para futuros pedidos http. Repara nas DEMONSTRAÇÕES

Comment: Miguel, não consigo compreender, teria como você fazer uma outra demonstração para mim utilizando um link no qual você puxa dados desse link ?

Comment: @Gennie tens o link a que queres fazer este parse, podes dar-me para eu dar uma olhada

Comment: Peguei esse de modo aleatório::https://www.netflix.com/br/login

Comment: Como faço pra dar curl (get) nesse link e pegar o value de "<input type="hidden" name="withFields" value="accessToken,rememberMe,nextPage" data-reactid="51"/><input type="hidden" name="authURL" value="1526639860898.gm/544CBTGsGINJNknmU2CHt5w0=" data-reactid="52"/>"

Comment: O value desse input muda a cada request

Comment: @Gennie, https://repl.it/repls/ZealousConventionalAnalysts

Comment: Muito obrigado!